# How to avoid getting into re.py while debugging

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am new to Python and I am using Eclipse(with PyDev), I am learning to debug the code but when I call re.search in my code the debugger gets into re.py module and takes multiple iterations to get out of it to come back to my script. 
Is there a way to disable debugger to get into the modules ?

Comment: It goes into `re.py` because you told the program to use the `re` module. What else do you expect it to do?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 , Is there a way to disable the debugger to skip getting into the modules ?

Comment: I haven't used `pydev`. However, in `pdb` there is a `step` command which sounds like what you are using. If you don't wish to go into a particular function call you can use the `next` command that takes you to the next line. This means that you would get to the point where it was about to get into `re` and then you would use `next` instead of `step` to go until this line has finished executing.

Comment: @skyler Are you referring to **step onto** ?

Comment: @Fenomatik I am explaining how it is done in `pdb`, the Python debugger that I know. I assume there is something analogous in the debugger you are using. I don't know what `step onto` is in the context of your debugger. So, yeah, that could be the same as `next` is in `pdb`.

Comment: @skyler I assume that @Fenomatik is asking for step filtering a very useful feature of Eclipse JDT that does not require you at each step to decide to step-into vs step-over as it implicitly skips the classes you don't care about. See http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm?cp=1_4_7_2_20  I don't know if PyDev has an equivalent. You can add the `@DontTrace` comment when you want to skip a method, but that does not answer the question as OP is not likely to want to edit the `re` module to add the comments everywhere.

Comment: @JonahGraham That sounds like a very cool feature and exactly what Fenomatik is looking for. Thanks for pointing that out.